# Any Plugin or suggested Design for user to perform an Custom action on Wordpress content

Tags: wordpress

I need to make a Wordpress website having lots of recipes.User will be allowed to read and click on "Cooked" button associated with that particular Article. I would like to store who all user have Cooked that recipe and show it when I am showing the Recipe.

Is there any plugin available which can store User Activities on content(like we have comments plugin) or else what should be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [**`WP Favorite Posts`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/) plugin which allows visitors to add favorite posts.

and set the label as "Cooked" instead of "add to favorites" , this will be the easiest way to do it but if you are up for some custom coding then it's simply a matter of saving the recipe post id in the user meta using [**`update_user_meta`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into update_user_meta. Will it be possible to have a many to Many mapping using this. As such, I user can cook many recipes and one Recipe can be cooked by many users.